# ReacMapboxGl Marker doesn't show on map

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

```
    import ReactMapboxGl, { Marker } from "react-mapbox-gl";
    import React from "react";
    
    const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
        accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN,
    });
    
    export default function App() {
        return (
            <Map
                style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
                containerStyle={{
                    height: "100vh",
                    width: "100vw",
                }}
                center={[-74.006, 40.7128]}
            >
                <Marker coordinates={[-74.006, 40.7128]}>
                    <div>IAM HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEERE</div>
                </Marker>
            </Map>
        );
    }
```

This is a basic map showing using mapbox-react-gl.
There is no bug showing in console log but I can not see the marker on the map.

Comment: I just found out the version after 5.0 is very unstable.I downgraded it to 4.8.6 now it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't set the coordinates correctly **(latitude, longitude)**

They should be, based in your example `[40.7128 -74.006]`